# Highcharts : use function in Serie data

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Is it possible to use a function in a serie data ? like this

My function :

```
function CalculBoucle(nbmin,nbmax,nbval)
{
CoordY = ['2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011'];
textAxeY = "";
var i;
for (i = nbmin; i < nbmax; i++) {
    textAxeY += "data.dataevolution["+nbval+"]"+".annee"+CoordY[i] + ",";
}

return textAxeY
}
```

My serie data :

```
 series: [      {
            name: [data.dataevolution[19].metier],
            data: [CalculBoucle(4,6,19)] //here my function
        }, 
            ]
```

Comment: The problem is that you are creating some string, while there should be array of points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$(function () {
    function test() {
        return [1,2,3,4]
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({

        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: test()
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vbd7pvz/1/

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't work because my function has variables.

Comment: Well works properly http://jsfiddle.net/4vbd7pvz/2/, second solution is using self-call function http://jsfiddle.net/4vbd7pvz/4/